# Update a JavaFX UI not through an onaction of one of its elements

Tags: user-interface, javafx

I'm trying to build an app that has a GUI in JavaFX and that GUI is supposed to get updated by a trigger that is new record received by Amazon kinesis consumer.
So I started playing with it a bit and tried to fill a circle in a color of my choosing (gold) when I get a new record, but to my surprise to GUI did not update
correctly. Even after I tried to run it with Platform.runlater as some questions here suggested.
When I debugged the code to my surprise I also found out that the FXML value of
the fill property does change, but it happens before my breakpoint that is
on the function handle, that supposed to change it (that is weird in itself).
But for some reason, my GUI still refuses to update.

If I create some button and trigger the entire process with it, it does change
the color of the circle though.

Help would be much appreciated.

Here is my process records function (monitoringLogic.updateUI updates the UI):

```
public void processRecords(List<Record> records, IRecordProcessorCheckpointer checkpointer) {
    long timestamp = 0;
    List<Long> seqNos = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Record r : records) {

        timestamp = Math.max(timestamp, Long.parseLong(r.getPartitionKey()));

        try {
            byte[] b = new byte[r.getData().remaining()];
            r.getData().get(b);
            seqNos.add(Long.parseLong(new String(b, "UTF-8").split("#")[0]));
            //this thread adds the transaction to the DB
            Thread addTransactionToDBThread = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(new String(b, "UTF-8").split("#")[1]);
                        Transaction transaction = Transaction.convertJsonToTransaction(jsonObj);
                        //add the transaction to the database
                        dataBase.addTransactionToDB(transaction);
                        //update the user-interface about the last transaction in the system
                        DATA_STATUS transactionStatus = monitoringLogic.getStatus(transaction);
                        monitoringLogic.updateUI(transaction.getUuid(), transaction.getSender(), transaction.getReceiver(), transactionStatus);
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            addTransactionToDBThread.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error parsing record", e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    synchronized (lock) {
        if (largestTimestamp.get() < timestamp) {
            log.info(String.format(
                    "Found new larger timestamp: %d (was %d), clearing state",
                    timestamp, largestTimestamp.get()));
            largestTimestamp.set(timestamp);
            sequenceNumbers.clear();
        }

        // Only add to the shared list if our data is from the latest run.
        if (largestTimestamp.get() == timestamp) {
            sequenceNumbers.addAll(seqNos);
            Collections.sort(sequenceNumbers);
        }
    }
    try {
        checkpointer.checkpoint();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error while trying to checkpoint during ProcessRecords", e);
    }
}
```

Here is my UI Controller:

```
package com.userInterface;

import com.DATA_STATUS;
import com.Main;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class UIController implements Observer {
    @FXML
    private TableView<Record> table = new TableView<Record>();
    @FXML
    public TableColumn<Record, String> legalFlow1 = new TableColumn<Record, String>();
    @FXML
    public TableColumn<Record, String> legalFlow2 = new TableColumn<Record, String>();
    @FXML
    public TableColumn<Record, String> legalFlow3 = new TableColumn<Record, String>();
    @FXML
    public TableColumn<Record, String> legalFlow4 = new TableColumn<Record, String>();
    @FXML
    public TableColumn<Record, String> legalFlow5 = new TableColumn<Record, String>();
    @FXML
    public TableColumn<Record, String> legalFlow6 = new TableColumn<Record, String>();
    @FXML
    public Button exitButton = new Button();
    @FXML
    public Circle legalFlow1circle1 = new Circle();


    public Map<String, String> circles = new HashMap<String, String>();
    //last changes
    public UIController() {
        fillMap();
    }

    @FXML
    /**
     * The function exits from the game
     */
    public void pressExitButton() {
        Main.dropDBSchema();
        System.exit(0);
    }


    public void actionPerformed() {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                handle();
            }
        });
    }

    public void handle() {
        legalFlow1circle1.setFill(Color.GOLD);
    }


        public void changeCircleColor(String key, DATA_STATUS status) {
        exitButton.fire();

    }

    private void fillMap() {
        this.circles.put("3866f99b-c412-4ce7-89dc-a53a06fa0fbc_ms1_ms2", "legalFlow1circle1");
        this.circles.put("3866f99b-c412-4ce7-89dc-a53a06fa0fbc_ms2_ms3", "legalFlow1circle2");
        this.circles.put("3866f99b-c412-4ce7-89dc-a53a06fa0fbc_ms3_ms4", "legalFlow1circle3");
        this.circles.put("a24854d9-1417-4468-852b-2fd442c844ce_ms3_ms1", "legalFlow2circle1");
        this.circles.put("a24854d9-1417-4468-852b-2fd442c844ce_ms1_ms2", "legalFlow2circle2");
        this.circles.put("332c464c-1b73-455e-800b-285683892285_ms4_ms2", "legalFlow3circle1");
        this.circles.put("332c464c-1b73-455e-800b-285683892285_ms2_ms3", "legalFlow3circle2");
        this.circles.put("332c464c-1b73-455e-800b-285683892285_ms3_ms1", "legalFlow3circle3");
        this.circles.put("ba3ef2e3-356e-4951-9854-f1803bb91653_ms2_ms1", "legalFlow4circle1");
        this.circles.put("ba3ef2e3-356e-4951-9854-f1803bb91653_ms1_ms4", "legalFlow4circle2");
        this.circles.put("ba3ef2e3-356e-4951-9854-f1803bb91653_ms4_ms3", "legalFlow4circle3");
        this.circles.put("b4fea051-d49c-46b9-a544-8cda3d4a8701_ms1_ms3", "legalFlow5circle1");
        this.circles.put("b4fea051-d49c-46b9-a544-8cda3d4a8701_ms3_ms2", "legalFlow5circle2");
        this.circles.put("02f77f86-0370-49a5-a26d-e3cfc2921d6c_ms3_ms2", "legalFlow6circle1");
        this.circles.put("02f77f86-0370-49a5-a26d-e3cfc2921d6c_ms2_ms4", "legalFlow6circle2");
        this.circles.put("02f77f86-0370-49a5-a26d-e3cfc2921d6c_ms4_ms1", "legalFlow6circle3");
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        actionPerformed();
    }
}
```

Here is my FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Circle?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="563.0" prefWidth="780.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.userInterface.UIController">
   <children>
      <Button id="exitButton" fx:id="exitButton" layoutX="787.0" layoutY="488.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#pressExitButton" text="Exit" />
      <TableView id="table" fx:id="table" layoutX="120.0" layoutY="199.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="730.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn id="legalFlow1" fx:id="legalFlow1" prefWidth="124.0" text="legalFlow1" />
            <TableColumn id="legalFlow2" fx:id="legalFlow2" prefWidth="121.0" text="legalFlow2" />
            <TableColumn id="legalFlow3" fx:id="legalFlow3" prefWidth="116.0" text="legalFlow3" />
            <TableColumn id="legalFlow4" fx:id="legalFlow4" prefWidth="120.0" text="legalFlow4" />
            <TableColumn id="legalFlow5" fx:id="legalFlow5" prefWidth="124.0" text="legalFlow5" />
            <TableColumn id="legalFlow6" fx:id="legalFlow6" prefWidth="124.0" text="legalFlow6" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
      <ListView id="legalFlow4Content" fx:id="legalFlow4Content" layoutX="479.0" layoutY="225.0" prefHeight="173.0" prefWidth="123.0" />
      <ListView id="legalFlow5Content" fx:id="legalFlow5Content" layoutX="602.0" layoutY="225.0" prefHeight="173.0" prefWidth="123.0" />
      <ListView id="legalFlow6Content" fx:id="legalFlow6Content" layoutX="725.0" layoutY="225.0" prefHeight="173.0" prefWidth="123.0" />
      <ListView id="legalFlow3Content" fx:id="legalFlow3Content" layoutX="364.0" layoutY="225.0" prefHeight="173.0" prefWidth="115.0" />
      <ListView id="legalFlow2Content" fx:id="legalFlow2Content" layoutX="241.0" layoutY="225.0" prefHeight="173.0" prefWidth="123.0" />
      <ListView id="legalFlow1Content" fx:id="legalFlow1Content" layoutX="118.0" layoutY="225.0" prefHeight="173.0" prefWidth="123.0" />
      <Circle id="legalFlow1circle3" fx:id="legalFlow1circle3" fill="#d6d8da" layoutX="135.0" layoutY="363.0" radius="12.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
      <Circle id="legalFlow1circle2" fx:id="legalFlow1circle2" fill="#d6d8da" layoutX="135.0" layoutY="311.0" radius="12.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
      <Circle id="legalFlow1circle1" fx:id="legalFlow1circle1" fill="#d6d8da" layoutX="135.0" layoutY="258.0" radius="12.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
      <Circle id="legalFlow2circle2" fx:id="legalFlow2circle2" fill="#d6d8da" layoutX="257.0" layoutY="342.0" radius="12.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
      <Circle id="legalFlow2circle1" fx:id="legalFlow2circle1" fill="#d6d8da" layoutX="256.0" layoutY="281.0" radius="12.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
      <Circle id="legalFlow3circle3" fx:id="legalFlow3circle3" fill="#d6d8da" layoutX="380.0" layoutY="364.0" radius="12.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
      <Circle id="legalFlow3circle2" fx:id="legalFlow3circle2" fill="#d6d8da" layoutX="380.0" layoutY="309.0" radius="12.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
      <Circle id="legalFlow3circle1" fx:id="legalFlow3circle1" fill="#d6d8da" layoutX="380.0" layoutY="254.0" radius="12.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
      <Circle id="legalFlow4circle3" fx:id="legalFlow4circle3" fill="#d6d8da" layoutX="494.0" layoutY="363.0" radius="12.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
      <Circle id="legalFlow4circle2" fx:id="legalFlow4circle2" fill="#d6d8da" layoutX="494.0" layoutY="308.0" radius="12.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
      <Circle id="legalFlow4circle1" fx:id="legalFlow4circle1" fill="#d6d8da" layoutX="495.0" layoutY="254.0" radius="12.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
      <Circle id="legalFlow5circle2" fx:id="legalFlow5circle2" fill="#d6d8da" layoutX="618.0" layoutY="340.0" radius="12.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
      <Circle id="legalFlow5circle1" fx:id="legalFlow5circle1" fill="#d6d8da" layoutX="618.0" layoutY="278.0" radius="12.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
      <Circle id="legalFlow6circle3" fx:id="legalFlow6circle3" fill="#d6d8da" layoutX="740.0" layoutY="363.0" radius="12.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
      <Circle id="legalFlow6circle2" fx:id="legalFlow6circle2" fill="#d6d8da" layoutX="740.0" layoutY="310.0" radius="12.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
      <Circle id="legalFlow6circle1" fx:id="legalFlow6circle1" fill="#d6d8da" layoutX="740.0" layoutY="257.0" radius="12.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
      <Label layoutX="151.0" layoutY="250.0" text="MS1 to MS2" />
      <Label layoutX="150.0" layoutY="302.0" text="MS2 to MS3" />
      <Label layoutX="151.0" layoutY="355.0" text="MS3 to MS4" />
      <Label layoutX="270.0" layoutY="273.0" text="MS3 to MS1" />
      <Label layoutX="270.0" layoutY="334.0" text="MS1 to MS2" />
      <Label layoutX="396.0" layoutY="246.0" text="MS4 to MS2" />
      <Label layoutX="395.0" layoutY="301.0" text="MS2 to MS3" />
      <Label layoutX="396.0" layoutY="355.0" text="MS3 to MS1" />
      <Label layoutX="510.0" layoutY="246.0" text="MS2 to MS1" />
      <Label layoutX="508.0" layoutY="300.0" text="MS1 to MS4" />
      <Label layoutX="508.0" layoutY="355.0" text="MS4 to MS3" />
      <Label layoutX="634.0" layoutY="269.0" text="MS1 to MS3" />
      <Label layoutX="635.0" layoutY="331.0" text="MS3 to MS2" />
      <Label layoutX="756.0" layoutY="250.0" text="MS3 to MS2" />
      <Label layoutX="756.0" layoutY="300.0" text="MS2 to MS4" />
      <Label layoutX="756.0" layoutY="355.0" text="MS4 to MS1" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And last, here is my main:

```
package com;

import com.kinesisdataconsumer.Consumer;
import com.kinesisdataproducer.Producer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main extends Application {
    public static Stage stage = new Stage();
    public static Parent root = new Parent() {
    };
    public static DataBase dataBase;

    /**
     * the main method of the program
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String legalFlowsFileName = "src/main/resources/legalFlows.json";
        String transactionFileName = "src/main/resources/transaction.json";

        //create the data base and add the tables
        dataBase = new DataBase();

        //run the spring boot application
        SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(Main.class);
        springApplication.run(args);

        //parse all the legal flows from 'legalFlows.json'
        LegalFlowsFileParser legalFlowsFileParser = new LegalFlowsFileParser(legalFlowsFileName);
        ArrayList<LegalFlow> legalFlows = legalFlowsFileParser.parseFile();
        dataBase.addAllLegalFlowsToDB(legalFlows);

        //parse all the transactions from 'transactions.json'
        TransactionsFileParser transactionsFileParser = new TransactionsFileParser(transactionFileName);
        ArrayList<Transaction> transactions = transactionsFileParser.parseFile();

        //Kinesis Producer
        Producer producer = new Producer(transactions);
        try {
            producer.produceData();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //create the monitoring logic of the whole system
        MonitoringLogicImpl monitoringLogic = new MonitoringLogicImpl(dataBase, legalFlows);

        //Kinesis consumer
        Thread thread = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                Consumer consumer = new Consumer(dataBase, transactions, monitoringLogic);
                consumer.consumeData();
            }
        };
        thread.start();

        Application.launch(Main.class, args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage){
        this.stage = stage;
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        try {
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/UserInterface.fxml"));
            this.root = loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stage.setTitle("Troubleshooting project");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 900, 700));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void dropDBSchema(){
        dataBase.dropSchema();
    }
}
```

Here is the monitoring logic class:

```
package com;

import com.userInterface.UIController;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

import java.util.UUID;

public class MonitoringLogicImpl extends Observable implements MonitoringLogic {
    private DataBase database ;
    private ArrayList<LegalFlow> legalFlows;
    private final int MAX_DELAY = 20;
    private UIController uiController;
    List<Observer> observers = new ArrayList<Observer>();

    public MonitoringLogicImpl(DataBase database, ArrayList<LegalFlow> legalFlows){
        this.database = database;
        this.legalFlows = legalFlows;
        this.uiController = new UIController();
        attach(this.uiController);
    }

    public DATA_STATUS getStatus(Transaction transaction){
        LegalFlow legalFlow = getLegalFlowAccordingToLegalFlowUUID(transaction.getUuid());
        if(legalFlow.isTransactionExistInLegalFlow(transaction)){
            if(!isTransactionArrivedInDelay(transaction.getTimeSent(), transaction.getTimeReceived())){
                //first case : status COMPLETE - the transaction exist in the DB and it is part of a legal flow
                return DATA_STATUS.COMPLETE;
            } else {
                //third case : status DELAY - the time from the transaction sent until it's received is above the threshold value(MAX_DELAY)
                return DATA_STATUS.DELAY;
            }
        } else{
            //third case : status ERROR - the transaction is not exist in the DB
            return DATA_STATUS.ERROR;
        }
    }

    public void updateUI(UUID flowUUID, String sender, String receiver, DATA_STATUS status){
       // String key = flowUUID.toString()+"_"+sender+"_"+receiver;
        //this.uiController.changeCircleColor(key, status);
        notifyAllObservers();
    }

    public LegalFlow getLegalFlowAccordingToLegalFlowUUID(UUID legalFlowUUID){
        for (LegalFlow lf:this.legalFlows){
            if(lf.getUUID().toString().equals(legalFlowUUID.toString())){
                return lf;
            }
        }
        return new LegalFlow(UUID.fromString("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"),"ms0");
    }

    public boolean isTransactionArrivedInDelay(String timeSent, String timeReceived){
        DateTime dateTimeSent= null, dateTimeReceived = null;
        try {
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");
            dateTimeSent = formatter.parseDateTime(timeSent);
            dateTimeReceived = formatter.parseDateTime(timeReceived);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long seconds = dateTimeReceived.getMillis() - dateTimeSent.getMillis();
         if((seconds/1000) > MAX_DELAY){
             return true;
         }
         return false;
    }
    //last changes
    public void attach(Observer observer){
        observers.add(observer);
    }

    public void notifyAllObservers(){
        Object obj = null;
        for (Observer observer : observers) {
            observer.update(this,obj);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What does `MonitoringLogicImpl#updateUI` look like?  I'm so invested in this project now!

Comment: First of all, thank you very much!
I've uploaded the monitoring logic class and edited the question.
Looking forward to your suggestions.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

So what you're doing is making an added `UIController` instance, which is why you're not getting a NullPointerException but also why you're not updating the actual `UIController` being used on the screen.

What you're essentially doing:

```
- new MonitoringLogicImpl
  - new UIController
  - Add to Observers
- Start FX
  - FXML Loads new UIController
```

The UIController you're debugging is not the same instance that is on the screen.  I posted on one of your colleagues posts that you need to somehow pass the FXML created UIController into the MonitoringLogicImpl:

```
- make `MonitoringLogicImpl monitoringLogic` a Main instance variable so that in `start` you can call something like `monitoringLogic.addListener(loader.getController())`
```

This will have limitations though, if you start adding other FXML screens which need to be updated.  You may want to do something more generic, where your application is the observer and it distributes messages to a mailbox, message bus or something else.

With regards to the app, what happens if someone closes it? There is no way to re-connect the gui without restarting the whole service?